# How do i minify all js files within a directory structure using javascript::minify module?

Tags: javascript, perl, file, yui, minify

I wanted to minify all js files in a directory tree using the minify module from the javascript::minify package but am unable to do the same.I was successful in doing it for individual files but when i run it for the entire directory , i get a warning message at line 345 in the minify.pm file.

Here is the code that i came up with:

```
use File::Find;
use JavaScript::Minifier qw(minify);

find(sub {
  if (-f and /\.js$/) {
    $t = 'temp.js';
    open(INFILE, $_) or die;
    open(OUTFILE, ">$t") or die;
    minify(input => *INFILE, outfile => *OUTFILE);
    close(INFILE);
    close(OUTFILE);
    rename($t,$_);
  }
}, '.');
```

Following is the code that works for individual files:

```
use JavaScript::Minifier qw(minify);

$file = 'ex.js';
$temp = 'temp.js';
open(INFILE, $file) or die;
open(OUTFILE, ">$temp") or die;
minify(input => *INFILE, outfile => *OUTFILE);
close(INFILE);
close(OUTFILE);
rename($temp,$file);
```

Please help with possible solutions..

Comment: What is the error message?
Is it failing inside of the find on ex.js?
If not, what happens if you run the individual version on the file that caused the problem in the recursive version?

Comment: This Bug is fixed in the latest version of the module.  v1.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`JavaScript::Minifier`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JavaScript::Minifier) complains with empty files.

The following demonstrates:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JavaScript::Minifier qw(minify);

print minify(input => '');
```

Outputs:

```
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/JavaScript/Minifier.pm line 345.
```

Therefore, you have a `.js` file somewhere that is completely empty.  The easy fix for this is just to verify that the file has data before you process it:

```
if (-f && -s && /\.js$/) {
```

However, I'd recommend some cleaning up of your script to the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Find;
use JavaScript::Minifier qw(minify);

find(sub {
    return unless -f && -s && /\.js$/;

    local @ARGV = my $file = $_;
    local $^I = '.bak';
    local $/;
    while (<>) {
        print minify(input => $_);
    }
    unlink "$file$^I"; # Optionally delete backup
}, '.');
```

Notes:

- You probably would've gotten an answer a lot faster if you included the exact warning message in your post.
- I've reported this bug to the module author: [minify produces warning for empty files](https://github.com/zoffixznet/JavaScript-Minifier/issues/3) (and it's [fixed](https://github.com/zoffixznet/JavaScript-Minifier/commit/a3a6ce8c0b6c4511eacb3909da76011255eec05c))